# Apache Virtual Host, host webside without alias

Tags: linux, apache, debian, webserver, vhosts

I can host a website using Alias.

Than the URI look like: **[www.myside.com/alias](http://www.myside.com/alias)**

I achive this using this in **/etc/apache2/sites-available/www.myside.com.conf**

```
 Alias /alias"/usr/local/tomcat/alias"
 <Directory "/usr/local/tomcat/alias">
     Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride AuthConfig
     Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

What I need is that I'm able to host the main context with this:
**[www.myside.com](http://www.myside.com)** and an image context with the alias, looking like this: **[www.myside.com/userimg](http://www.myside.com/userimg)**. So I only need the main `<Directory></Directory>` block without the alias.

By the way, I'm using JKmount.

The image context:

```
 Alias /userimg "/usr/local/tomcat/userimg"
      <Directory "/usr/local/tomcat/userimg">
         Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride AuthConfig
         Require all granted
      </Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading your question, I assume that:

- your site is not SSL.
- therefore it will use port 80
- you have a site, lets say http://www.example.com
- the files for your site are stored in `/usr/local/tomcat/alias`
- the main page for your site is `index.html`, under `/usr/local/tomcat/alias`
- the image files for your site are sorted in `/usr/local/tomcat/userimg`
- in your HTML files, you reference other pages like this:

  ```
  <a href="otherpage.html">Other page</a>
  ```
- you reference images like this:

  ```
  <img src="userimg/someimage.png" alt="Some Image">
  ```

Your configuration would look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined

    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/tomcat/alias"
    DirectoryIndex index.html

    Alias "/userimg" "/usr/local/tomcat/userimg"

    <Directory "/usr/local/tomcat/alias">
        Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

---

If you want to avoid any `Alias` at all, you could create a softlink in `/usr/local/tomcat/alias` to `/usr/local/tomcat/userimg`.

```
cd /usr/local/tomcat/alias
ln -s /usr/local/tomcat/userimg userimg
```

And you will have to allow Apache to follow links in the `<Directory>` directives.

---

Or you could move your images under `/usr/local/tomcat/alias/userimg`.

Comment: Everything as expected